i have an error with the gradel error and i have tried to correct it but its not working out
issues with the gradel the error is the below one
"Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'."
i tried to update gradel  it hinders the app from running and that what i want to run the app
